# VS 2017 intellisense issue with ValueTuple

Tags: visual-studio-2017, valuetuple

Visual Studio 2017 Pro in Windows 7 with .net framework 4.7 developer kit installed and without System.ValueTuple nuget.

[image: intellisense suggestion]
[image: intellisense result]

Intellisense provides the correct tuple name in the suggestion list, but when chosen, writes the old tuple name (Item1, Item2, etc.)

Is this a Visual Studio bug, or a settings issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Resharper bug. I upgraded Resharper to 2017.1.3 and now intellisense resolves correctly.